# add an image field to wordpress category

Tags: php, database, wordpress

i am trying to add an image field to the `wp_term` table in the `database`, I'll call it `icon`.

I want that filed to contain a `URL` to an image that will be the thumb for the category.
I have already added the field to the `DB` and I have also inserted it into the code in the admin panel :

```
<?php if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy) ) : ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="icon"><?php _ex(' Icon', 'Taxonomy Icon'); ?></label></th>
        <td><input name="icon" id="icon" type="text" value="<?php if ( isset( $tag->icon ) ) echo esc_attr($tag->icon); ?>" size="40" />
        <p class="description"><?php _e('The &#8220;icon&#8221; is the URL to the category icon. if it is an uploaded image it will be http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/wp-content/uploads/{your_file.name}.'); ?></p></td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; // is_taxonomy_hierarchical() ?>
```

the code shows the content from the `database` if it is preset but doesnt update it.

what/where do i need to add so that it will also update the `DB` `icon` field?

thank you.

Comment: and after an hour its lost forever in the stack-overflow archives. faster then a post on 9gag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found a nice plugin that lets you add all kinds of fields to a post called [Category Meta plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=wp-category-meta) and its vary easy to use.

good luck :)